# Unity 2D limiting the rotation of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 3D to create a 2D rotating knob, I managed to achieve its rotation with this code:

```
    var speed = 5f;
    Vector2 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Now I want to limit the knob rotation between 0 and 270 degrees. How can I achieve that?

Comment: can't you just `Mathf.Clamp(angle, 0f, 270f)` ?

Comment: I love one line solutions. Thanks!
Does Clamp accept multiple bands? Like: between 0 and 50 or 80 and 110?

Comment: no, it doesn't unfortunately, but you could implement that yourself

Comment: my problem is that clamp stops at the closest value.. since it's a rotating knob, if it's on max (270f) and the user keeps rotating, it will suppress for a while but then rotate to 0 again whereas it should be blocked and only spin on the opposite diretction when it reaches max.

Comment: Where are you using `Mathf.Clamp`? I think it should happen upon assignment of `angle`, as in: `float angle = Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f, 0f, 270f);`

Comment: great, thanks man!